# AS3 Board Game How to draw 15x15 square board

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm creating a board game in AS3 for a Uni project.  I was wondering if someone could tell me the best method for creating a 15x15 board of squares on the stage?  I want to be able to add a mouse rollover effect on the squares.  Also when a player clicks on the board their counter will be placed on that square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty basic problem. Two dimensional board = you will need to use two loops one inside of other.

```
var myArrayOfTiles:Array = new Array();

var distanceX:Number = 0;
var distanceY:Number = 0;
for(var i:Number = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    myArrayOfTiles[i] = new Array();
    for(var j:Number = 0; j < 15; j++) {
        myArrayOfTiles[i][j] = new mySquare();
        myArrayOfTiles[i][j].x = distanceX;
        myArrayOfTiles[i][j].y = distanceY;
        distanceX += myArrayOfTiles[i][j].width;
    }
    distanceX = 0;
    distanceY += myArrayOfTiles[i][j].height;
}
```

That way you will have positioned tiles and two-dimensional array where you can access them. You can add listeners just after creating them.

**Edit:** Flash Professional version:

```
var myArrayOfTiles:Array = [];

var distanceX:Number = 0;
var distanceY:Number = 0;
for(var i:Number = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    myArrayOfTiles[i] = new Array();
    for(var j:Number = 0; j < 15; j++) {
    var mySquare:Symbol1 = new Symbol1();
        addChild(mySquare);
        myArrayOfTiles[i][j] = mySquare;
        myArrayOfTiles[i][j].x = distanceX;
        myArrayOfTiles[i][j].y = distanceY;
        distanceX += mySquare.width + 1;
    }
    distanceX = 0;
    distanceY += mySquare.height + 1;
}
```

That should work with FP, I checked this.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help.  Was wondering, why do I get errors on lines 5 6 and 7 when I try your code?  1084: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before right paren.  1084: Syntax error expecting colon before leftbracket.  1083: Syntax error  : for is unexpected.

Comment: A little typo, just fixed it.

Comment: Ok great.  Do you have any idea why i get the error, TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor. I take it mySquare is meant to be a square the size of one tile which is a movieClip exported for Actionscript?

Comment: This is probably some problem with your code. You need to provide more information on how you used my snipped. And/or what line of code error shows.

Comment: It's just placed at the start of the second frame. Also created this variable. `var mySquare = new BoardTile;` Which is a small red square i drew onto the stage and exported as a movieclip.  The error just states `TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
 at Main/frame2()`

Comment: I didn't know you are using FP. I added new version, this should work, just be sure that you have "mySquare" in library, and exported to frame1 with proper name of class.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is probably caused because you did not use the correct syntax to create your variable. It should be:

```
var mySquare:BoardTile = new BoardTile();
```

Also, you can add the mouseEventListener directly while creating your board, as well as make the tiles react to the mouse like they are a button. You do that like this:

```
var myArrayOfTiles:Array = [];

var distanceX:Number = 0;
var distanceY:Number = 0;
for(var i:Number = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    myArrayOfTiles[i] = new Array();
    for(var j:Number = 0; j < 15; j++) {
    var mySquare:Symbol1 = new Symbol1();
        mySquare.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fnClick); //adding the eventlistener
        mySquare.buttonMode = true; //now the cursor changes when you mouse over the square, to indicate you can interact with it
        addChild(mySquare);
        myArrayOfTiles[i][j] = mySquare;
        myArrayOfTiles[i][j].x = distanceX;
        myArrayOfTiles[i][j].y = distanceY;
        distanceX += mySquare.width + 1;
    }
    distanceX = 0;
    distanceY += mySquare.height + 1;
}
```